# "Reliable" Funds - Has anybody encountered this term before and in what context?

Tags: contract-law

2. Sources of your funds are legal and reliable, and you trade digital assets such as BTC out of my willingness. You guarantee that this Huobi account is for your own use only, and you will not engage in any illegal and criminal activities including money laundering and fraud. All of the information provided is true, legitimate, and up-to-date. In case of any violation of the aforesaid pledge,all economic and legal liabilities arising therefrom shall be borne by yourself.
   [huobi.com](https://c2c.huobi.com/en-us/senior/)

Comment: I don't have enough context (the site is password protected) to determine if what is really intended is the term of art "good funds" (e.g. a wire transfer or a cashier's check which can't "bounce"), possibly due to a translation issue, or if a different meaning is intended, and if so, what is intended. The entire paragraph is not written in fluent English suggesting a translation may be involved and that the meaning of the original may not be clearly expressed.

Comment: I think they mean BTC that has been through a mixer is not reliable, but that is far from clear.  Also their [User Agreement](https://www.huobi.com/support/en-us/detail/360000298561), [Privacy Policy](https://www.huobi.com/support/en-us/detail/360000298601), [Trading Regulation](https://www.huobi.com/support/en-us/detail/360000301401) and [KYC rules](https://www.huobi.com/support/en-us/detail/360000121402) do not have that text.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, I have encountered the term [reliable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reliable)

> Someone or something that is reliable can be trusted or believed because he, she, or it works or behaves well in the way you expect:

In context, it means the money will be there when they ask for it.

Comment: -1 While that is surely the correct meaning of "reliable" and **might** be the meaning of "reliable funds" in context, It is not safe to try to determine the meaning of a compound term from the meaning of its elements. No one, for example, could correctly deduce the meaning of "Critical Race Theory" from the meanings of the three words used in it. If "reliable funds" is a term of art, or more likely a mis-translation of a term of art in some other language, it might have a different meaning. For example, it could mean funds available on a regular basis, like a salary, not irregular earnings.